# How to add excerpt in loop in Twenty Eleven theme?

Tags: loop, excerpt, theme-twenty-twelve

Here is my loop code located in `index.php` file. I am using Twenty Eleven theme.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php twentytwelve_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>
```

Where should I add the `the_excerpt()` or any excerpt code into this?

Content code from my content.php

```
<div class="entry-content">
        <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?>
        <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentytwelve' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twenty Eleven uses already a conditional statement in ***content.php*** to show the excerpt in search results -

```
<?php if ( is_search() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search ?
```

edit this conditional to include the other templates where you want to show the excerpt;

example:

```
<?php if ( is_search() || is_home() || is_archive() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search, Posts Page and Archives ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just open the file `content.php` in the theme. You can [read this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part).

Comment: I already have the content.php file in my theme. But when I replace "the_excerpt" into that file excerpt also appears in single post. i just added the content code from content.php file in my question.